# Compiling C++ code (BASIC Interpreter) into ARM assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, arm, raspberry-pi, basic

I'm writing a basic command line operating system for the raspberry pi, much like those on computers from the 70's and early 80's. I have made the basic text input / output with assembly and would like to incorporate a BASIC interpreter into my code. I was thinking of writing my own version of BASIC and an interpreter in C++/Java (maybe not, since it's compiled into bytecode) then compiling it into ARM assembly for the raspberry pi, is this possible?

P.S I considered writing it in assembly, but figured that would be too complicated for my abilities.

Comment: Asking a "yes or no?"-type question about whether program X is possible to write in language Y isn't particularly useful. Your own capability is more likely to determine the answer than your choice of programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible since once you have a C++ compiler for your taget platform. You can use any language you want/need to, including Java since once all needed tools to compile/interpret are available in the target platform. You can do in assembly too. But do you really need/want to? it's really a lot of job without no much fun.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it is possible to write a small bit of assembly code that will then run a jvm, which will then run compiled java code?
@The Mask

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Once everything is converted to assembly and then binary, you can do yourself the assembly coding. But it isn't by no means small. Rather, a very small BASIC interpreter in assembly is a lot of assembly think about how large could be a JVM. Why are you looking for do these things in assembly? any specific reason you must use it instead of something more friendly and high-level like C or C++?

Comment: My overall objective is to write an operating system in java for the raspberry pi. I assumed that the way to do this would be to launch a JVM with assembly (since assembly is run when the computer is turned on) and then run the rest of the operating system with java.
@The Mask

Comment: Use a java compiler which do generate native code instead of. So, also your OS you can use Java to everything (including the BASIC intepreter) to build your stuff. Computers don't care which languages was this written in, just want to the right binary code to run.

Comment: Also, I know you're not asking for that, but it's a bit unusual write an OS in Java (also the one sun call "OS", I haven't hear never about one ) language. Actually it's unusual in a language which isn't C/C++. Have you considered this? You need to use pointers/assembly inling and do a lot of low-level coding (that's why C was created for) you need to find a native Java compiler (very probably not offcial) which do support all this. And well enough.